# Get url from another page

Tags: php, wordpress, url, html, permalinks

I'm very new to PHP so maybe its a very simple question.

One page1.php I want to show the url of page2.php

I tried it like this:

One page1.php:

```
<?php
$url1="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

On page2.php:

```
<?php 
echo $url1; ?>
```

Its a wordpress installation so I need url with permalinks.

maybe its a noob question but I only need to know how this works.
Thanks!

Comment: The right hand doesn't know what the left hand is doing, unless they're holding on to each other. In other words, how does page 2 know what page 1 contains? Use sessions if you're going to do that, or do an include.

Answer (score 0):

You should put them running one time, then page2.php can receive the url.

For example: in page2.php, include page1.php before echo.

So in page2.php:

```
<?php 
include 'page1.php';
echo $url1; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few alternative solutions for that. I'd advice using `file_get_contents` function.

Example usage:

```
$url1 = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$page1 = file_get_contents($url1);
echo $page1;
```

See more details here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Where do I need to put this script?? Thanks!

Comment: this script would display the url of page 1 so this goes on the top of the page1.php file i guess

Comment: My example shows how you can show any url from a different url. So let's say you want to show http://www.myblog.com/page1 content from http://www.myblog.com/page2. You basicly set $url1 to page1's url and put this script above in page2. You don't need any other code except PHP tag.

Comment: You can even write everything in a single line like <?php echo file_get_contents("<your other url here>"); ?>